# Android Button ArrayList onClickListener doesn't work. Why?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener

I created an arraylist for the buttons and tablerows.

```
private ArrayList<Button> btDec = new ArrayList<Button>();
private ArrayList<TableRow> tr = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
```

Then I want to create a new button and tablerow and add tem to the tablelayout by using the following code in the onCreate() method.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btDec.add(new Button(this));
            tr.add(new TableRow(this));

            int i = tr.size() - 1;
            btDec.get(i).setId(i);
            btDec.get(i).setText("-");
            tr.get(i).addView(btDec.get(i));
            lo.addView(tr.get(i), new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    });
```

All of this code works fine.
But the following code (also in the onCreate() method) doesn't work. If I press the button, nothing happens and it doesn't print anything in the Logcat.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++)
    {
        btDec.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.i("ButtonListener", "test");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++)
    {
        btDec.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.i("ButtonListener", "test");
            }
        });
    }
```

You can't do it in `onCreate()` because `tr` list there is empty! You should add onClick listener when you create a button.